# Set days to respective quarter in quarterly format

Tags: date, indexing

I have a database of the following type:

```
            Y033RD3Q086SBEA     CONSDEF     PERIC  ...      PCDG  COMPNFB  FEDFUNDS
1994-01-01          135.474   68.102186  2.914123  ...   588.824   52.651      3.05
1994-04-01          135.724   68.477710  2.886523  ...   598.721   53.074      3.56
1994-07-01          135.427   68.966372  2.841751  ...   609.310   53.067      4.26
1994-10-01          134.544   69.321509  2.789701  ...   631.830   53.481      4.76
1995-01-01          133.984   69.661335  2.744497  ...   621.252   53.799      5.53
                    ...         ...       ...  ...       ...      ...       ...
2014-10-01           99.149  111.754096  0.761446  ...  1269.727  105.171      0.09
2015-01-01           99.144  111.340463  0.756917  ...  1282.177  106.534      0.11
2015-04-01           98.943  111.902682  0.744341  ...  1307.650  107.357      0.12
2015-07-01           98.508  112.379110  0.732450  ...  1316.681  107.839      0.13
2015-10-01           98.102  112.506108  0.723991  ...  1317.079  107.616      0.12
```

As one clearly sees, every data point refers to a specific quarter. However, I'd like to have the date index displayed in quarter format, for example 1994-01-01 would be 1994Q1, 1994-04-01 would be 1994Q2 and so on. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution which looks very simple. I post it here in case it turns helpful for someone:

```
df.index=pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq='Q')
```

which trivially changes the index of the dataframe `df` displayed above into the quarterly correspondent.